# Head of my linked list is being overwritten

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list of people containing their name and birth date information. The person info is declared in a struct and when I create a newNode, that newNode is later added to the end of the list. What's happening is, I'm getting an infinite loop in my insertNode function because, somehow, the head of my list is being changed in my createNode function. Sometimes what I have works and other times it doesn't, which makes me believe I'm doing something small wrong that I'm just not catching.

I posted the code below. There is more to main than that, but I didn't post it since it's fine up till that point.

```
typedef struct info
{
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    struct info *next;
} person;

person *createNode(char *fName, char *lName, char *m, int d, int y)
{
    person *n = malloc(sizeof(person));
    n->firstName = strdup(fName);
    n->lastName = strdup(lName);
    n->month = convertMonthCharToInt(m);
    n->day = d;
    n->year = y;
    n->next = NULL;

    return n;
}

person *insertNode(person *head, person *newNode)
{
    person *temp = NULL;
    temp = head;

    if(head == NULL)
        return newNode;

    for(temp = head; temp->next!=NULL; temp = temp->next);

    if(head->next == NULL)
        head->next = newNode;

    return head;
}

int main()

{
    int numClasses = 0, numStudents = 0, numQueries = 0, d = 0, y = 0, j = 0;
    char fName[31], lName[31], m[11], queryFirstName[31], queryLastName[31];
    person *print;

    FILE *readFile = fopen("birthday2.txt", "r");

    if(readFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File does not exist. Closing program.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fscanf(readFile, "%d", &numClasses);

    while(i<numClasses)
    {
        person *head = malloc(sizeof(person));
        person *newNode = malloc(sizeof(person));
        person *result = malloc(sizeof(person));
        head = NULL;
        fscanf(readFile, "%d", &numStudents);
        j = 0;
        while(j<numStudents)
        {
            //read names in from file
            fscanf(readFile, "%s", &fName);
            fscanf(readFile, "%s", &lName);
            fscanf(readFile, "%s", &m);
            fscanf(readFile, "%d", &d);
            fscanf(readFile, "%d", &y);
            fscanf(readFile, "%d", &numQueries);

            //creates a node. My list head changes from here
            newNode = createNode(fName, lName, m, d, y);
            //to here. So I'm pretty sure it's changing within this function. Just not sure why.
            head = insertNode(head, newNode);
}
```

Comment: In your `insertNode` function, you iterate to the end of the list via for loop, but you don't add the node to the end of the list. You need to add `temp->next = newNode`. Don't really like the name `insertNode` as `insert` gives the impression that you provide an index at which to insert an item. `Add`, `Append` make much more sense as function names.

Also in main you allocate space for `person *head` and immediately set it to NULL. You don't need to allocate space for a pointer if you want it to point to NULL, or existing data. You only `malloc` to create new data.

Comment: Yea, my fault. The temp->next part was in there before. I took it out for a sec to see if I could get this to recursively insert just for giggles. The problem though is my head pointer changes inside my createNode function and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Looks like you are missing code. You might want to update the rest of it.

Comment: I added a line in main that was missing. Everything else in main after that is merge sort stuff and figuring out who has the closest birthday. That stuff all works as long as the head of my list is correct. Which right now, it's not at times.

Comment: I think you don't need either of `person *head = malloc(sizeof(person));` or `person *newNode = malloc(sizeof(person));` at the beginning of your outer loop. Just initialize both to NULL. As it is, the memory allocated by the first `malloc` call actually leaks, since you overwrite the pointer directly afterwards.

Comment: Did you post all the code here? Looks like insertNode has incomplete code. This code for(temp = head; temp->next!=NULL; temp = temp->next); does nothing. Did you forget to copy a body of this cycle to the post?